# SQL get record that matches FIRST date criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have the following

```
user_id job_id job_offer_date 
------- ------ --------------
1          123     2013-05-10 
1          124     2013-07-19
2          127     2013-05-10
3          128     2013-06-15
```

I want to write TWO separate queries here to use in a report:

**QUERY #1 (I have this working already)**

This query wants to return all users whose FIRST job offer date is by 2013-5-10.  This is an easy query because if the user has ANY jobs by that date, it will return him.  In this case, I'll see users #1, #2.

This query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.* FROM job WHERE j.job_offer_date <= '2013-05-10'
```

**QUERY #2 (This is my real question)**

How do I return users whose FIRST job offer date is AFTER 2013-5-10 and BEFORE 2013-7-19.  In this case, because user #1 has his FIRST offer by 2013-5-10, he should NOT be included in the results. This result set should ONLY include user #3.

The most important key here is because user #1 has his FIRST offer by 2013-5-10, he should be **excluded** from the result set in query #2.

Comment: you can use where condition like job_offer_date > '2013-05-10' and job_offer_date < '2013-05-10'

Comment: This doesn't work due to the last sentence in my original post.

Comment: Do you need to get just user_ids or for each user you need all rows that table has for him?

Comment: I just need the user_ids actually.  I need to make sure I'm bucketing my users only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of relevant first job offers.

```
select user_id, min(job_offer_date) as first_offer
from job
group by user_id
having min(job_offer_date) > '2013-05-10'
   and min(job_offer_date) < '2013-07-19'
```

Join on that set to get the users. I'd guess that user data is stored in a user table.

```
select u.*
from users u
inner join (select user_id, min(job_offer_date) as first_offer
            from job
            group by user_id
            having min(job_offer_date) > '2013-05-10'
               and min(job_offer_date) < '2013-07-19') o
        on o.user_id = u.user_id;
```

Comment: Your guess regarding a user table is correct. Trying this out.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember my SQL date stuff correctly, wouldn't it look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.* FROM job WHERE j.job_offer_date > '2013-05-10' AND j.job_offer_data < '2013-7-19'
```

EDIT: I misunderstood your question. The above would look for any user with a job between (but not on) the two dates listed. Oleh Nechytailo has a better answer.

Comment: This doens't work because it doesn't exclude the first user. He DOES have a match for these critieria, but he needs to be excluded due to his FIRST job.  Check out the last sentence in the original post.

Comment: nope, he wants to check only FIRST job offer date that match this interval

Comment: Ah, I understand now. My code would return only user 3 (because I used < and > to exclude the others) but it isn't a general solution. Updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, job_id, job_offer_date
from 
    (select user_id
        , job_id
        , job_offer_date
        , row_number() over 
                (partition by user_id order by job_offer_date) rown 
     from job) sub
where sub.rown = 1 and sub.job_offer_date > '2013-05-10' and sub.job_offer_date < '2013-07-19'
```

Answer (score 0):

it will definitely work

```
WITH TEMP 
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Job AS J
)

SELECT *
FROM TEMP AS A
WHERE OFFERdATE > '2013-05-10' AND oFFERdATE < '2013-7-19' AND
1 = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP WHERE OFFERdATE <= '2013-05-10' AND USERID = A.USERID) > 0 THEN      0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--------------
-- sample data
--------------
declare @data table
(
    user_id int,
    job_id int,
    job_offer_date datetime
)

insert into @data (user_id, job_id, job_offer_date) values 
    (1, 123, '2013-05-10'),
    (1, 124, '2013-07-19'),
    (2, 127, '2013-05-10'),
    (3, 128, '2013-06-15')

-----------
-- solution
-----------
select user_id from @data
group by user_id
having min(job_offer_date) > '2013-05-10' and min(job_offer_date) < '2013-07-19'
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without JUST selecting the user_id column?

Comment: @AdamLevitt You can add "min(job_offer_data)" in column list. If job_id of the first job offer is required as well, then Oleh Nechytailo's query is what you need.

Comment: What if I need like 35 columns?

Comment: @AdamLevitt Just add them after "job_offer_date" column in Oleh's solution. Or do you mean columns from another table?

Comment: @AdamLevitt For this case I can't think of a better approach than suggested by Mike.